# When I expend a dropdown, it's being hidden behind my footer. How do I push the footer down and allow the user to scroll?

Tags: html, css

I've pretty much got a menu that when the user clicks on an item, expands into a description of the item. The menu fits neatly between the header and footer without anything expanded but once I expand an item, the content begins to disappear behind the footer. However, the content that disappears is just the background, the text sits just above the footer. I really just want the entire menu to have white-space above and below that stays consistent even when an item's description has been expanded.

I've tried to add margins and padding to everything to ensure there's still spacing between the content and footer but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Here's the code I'm using the footer:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 5%;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* FOOTER */
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1D3557;
    color: #F1FAEE;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index: 2;
}

.footer-col {
    width: 33.3333%;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

And here's the code for the element I'm trying to get to stay above the footer:

```
.menu-card {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 80%;
    height: auto;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    border-radius: 10px;
    
}

.menu-items {
    position: absolute;
    width: 110%;
    min-height: 70%;
    height: auto;

    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.1rem;

    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);

    background: #1d3557;
    border-radius: 10px;

    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

I'm using  tags to create the little dropdown sections for each item.

EDIT:

Forgot to add the html for the menu and footer. Here it is now:

```
<div class="menu-card" id="dairy-menu">
    <h1><b>Dairy Items</b></h1>
    <div class="menu-items">
        <details>
            <summary>Dairy Item #1</summary>
            <span>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <button type="button">Add Calories</button>
            </span>
        </details>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="footer-col">
                <h4>Developer</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-col">
                <h4><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-col">
                <h4>Counter</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I've just included a single menu item, but there are 6 per menu. Not sure if that really matters.

P.S - Apoligies for this being so messy, I'm not entirely sure as to how to ask questions and such and what content I should include.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would checkout [mcve] that will assist you in deciding on what code is needed to post and what can be left out. Because that will allow users to post a working test.

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Try and put the code in a snippet or a fiddle. The code doesn't reproduce what you're describing.

Comment: Hi ruleboy21, would you mind describing what it is you can't recreate? I've forgot to remove a "display: none;" I had in the menu-card, but I've removed that now. I've also tested it on JSFiddle and it works as somewhat-intended.

Answer (score 1):

based on what you mention :

> *once I expand an item, the content begins to disappear behind the footer*

you are using `Z-index : 2` on the `footer` so if you dont have anything else you want the footer to overlap then change it to 0
you can bisacally control how elements overlap each other using `Z-index`

also use your menu id :

```
#dairy-menu{
  z-index : 99;
}
```

because **#id** in css can obliterate a **.class** when they both set on the same element 
*and in your model you have an ID and Class set on the same element*

 so keep that in mind .

using this method now your menu does not disappear behind your footer :

```css
#dairy-menu{
  z-index : 99;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 5%;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* FOOTER */
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1D3557;
    color: #F1FAEE;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index: 0;
}

.footer-col {
    width: 33.3333%;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.menu-card {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 80%;
    height: auto;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    border-radius: 10px;
    
}

.menu-items {
    position: absolute;
    width: 110%;
    min-height: 70%;
    height: auto;

    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.1rem;

    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);

    background: #1d3557;
    border-radius: 10px;

    justify-content: space-around;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-card" id="dairy-menu">
    <h1><b>Dairy Items</b></h1>
    <div class="menu-items">
        <details>
            <summary>Dairy Item #1</summary>
            <span>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <p>Dairy Item #1 description.</p>
                <button type="button">Add Calories</button>
            </span>
        </details>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="footer-col">
                <h4>Developer</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-col">
                <h4><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-col">
                <h4>Counter</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hi THE NEXT SJ, this helps preventing the menu from hiding underneath the footer. However, I was hoping to ensure that there is still white-space between the menu and footer. When the menu item's expand, instead of overlapping the footer it would instead push the footer down to maintain a gap between that and the menu.

Thank you for this though!